# pylance giving false negative import error in vscode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, pylance

I succesfully connect jupyter notebook in *external server linux* in my organization `http://100.96.0.29:8888/?token=...` through vscode in my *laptop windows*.

I also succesfully installed some dependencies such as cupy through first cell `%pip install cupy`.

I also succesfully import cupy through second cell:

```
import cupy as cp #Import "cupy" could not be resolved Pylance(reportMissingImport)

x_gpu = cp.array([1, 2, 3])
x_gpu
```

Giving me output:

```
array([1, 2, 3])
```

But, why pylance report missing import?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You've installed `cupy` on the remote Jupyter server, not on your local machine.

Pylance doesn't know about the packages installed on the remote Jupyter server, so it reports a missing import when you try to import `cupy`.

One way is to install `cupy` on your local machine. But this seems to contradict the original intention of using remote.

Another way is to disable the warning provided by Pylance, you could add the following codes to your `settings.json`:

```json
"python.analysis.diagnosticSeverityOverrides": {
    "reportMissingImports": "none"
}
```